# Trying to figure out the return value from frontend console

Tags: dapps, frontend

So, I called a function from my smart contract that is supposed to return the address of a new contract instance, but I'm not sure how to read the output from the console.

This is the image of my console output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the return value of a transaction.

They are only available to other functions and contracts unless you are calling in read only mode, i.e. not a transaction.

Have a look here
[Why is it impossible to get return values of state-changing calls?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66746/why-is-it-impossible-to-get-return-values-of-state-changing-calls)

Or here https://blog.b9lab.com/calls-vs-transactions-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-62d6b17d0bc2

Hope it helps

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. I'll try to work around the problem using this information

Answer (score 0):

No, `r` is one of the values of the ECDSA signature. ECDSA is a digital signature algorithm that uses elliptic curve and this algorithm is used to create the key pairs used in the signing and verification process of digital signatures.

See:

[What does v, r, s in eth_getTransactionByHash mean?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15766/what-does-v-r-s-in-eth-gettransactionbyhash-mean)

Comment: ah, I see. In that case, what is the address that is supposed to be returned?